# LINQ filter condition

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have two tables:

```
People (~10000 Record)
PID Primary Key

PeopleCharater (~500000 Record)
OID Primary Key
PID Foreign Key
RecordDate(DateTime of the record is created)
```

Its a one to many relation, One PID have multiple OID.

I wan to select a list of OID that matched the Hashset(Of PID) and the RecordDate between a StartDate and EndDate
The tricky part is, The greatest RecordDate that <= StartDate should be included.

Example:

```
PeopleCharacter
OID PID RecordDate
a   1   2014-10-09
b   1   2015-12-10
c   1   2015-12-15
d   1   2016-02-25
```

The record retrieved should be a b and c if StartDate is 2015-01-01 to 2015-12-31.

How do I write a LINQ query to retrieve the record?

My Current Code:

```
Dim PIDHash as Hashset(Of PID)(~10000 PID)
db.Filter(Function(x) x.RecordDate >= StartDate andalso x.RecordDate <= EndDate andalso PIDHash.contains(x.PID)).
   Union(??? another filter to select the greatest RecordDate < StartDate)
```

The number of times retrieve from database must be limited due to performance issues. Stored Procedure solution is accepted.

Comment: You are retrieving the entire contents of the People table and then sending it back to the database to use as a filter?

Comment: I'm getting the entire People table from from User Input, and retrieve every people character that matched the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Figure out with the help of my senior.

```
Dim query = db.PeopleCharacter.Where(Function(p) PIDHash.Contains(p.PID))
Dim RecordDateQuery = query.Where(Function(y) y.RecordDate <= StartDate).
                            GroupBy(Function(x) x.PID).
                            Select(Function(f) New With {.PID = f.key, .RecordDate = f.Max(Function(t) t.RecordDate)})
Dim results = query.Where(Function(p) p.RecordDate >= StartDate AndAlso p.RecordDate <= EndDate).
                  Union(query.Join(RecordDateQuery,
                                   Function(x) New With {.PID = x.PID, .RecordDate = x.RecordDate},
                                   Function(y) New With {.PID = y.PID, .RecordDate = y.RecordDate},
                                   Function(x, y) x))
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# it would be:

```
var query=db.PeopleCharacter
  .Where(p=>PIDHash.Contains(p.PID));
var results=query
  .Where(p=>p.RecordDate>=StartDate && p.RecordDate<=EndDate)
  .Union(
    query.Where(p=>p.RecordDate<StartDate)
      .OrderByDescending(p=>p.RecordDate)
      .Take(1)
  );
```

Using an online converter to VB.NET gives:

```
Dim query = db.PeopleCharacter.Where(Function(p) PIDHash.Contains(p.PID))
Dim results = query.Where(Function(p) p.RecordDate >= StartDate AndAlso p.RecordDate <= EndDate).Union(query.Where(Function(p) p.RecordDate < StartDate).OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.RecordDate).Take(1))
```

Comment: The Union part only return one OID for the Top Most PID, i need to get OID for every PID.